# Android Studio no Fedora com erro: Ignoring unknown package filter 'platform-tools'

Tags: android, android-studio

Estou tentando instalar o *Android Studio* no Fedora 23 e ocorre o seguinte problema:

No Console de Detalhes da Instalação:

> Ignoring unknown package filter 'platform-tools'

Em um Pop-up informando:

> the following SDK component was not installed: platform-tools

Alguém tem alguma ideia do que pode ser e como resolver?

Isso não deixa continuar a instalação.

Imagem da tela:

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Obrigado @GuilhermeNascimento , irei fazer essa alteração, coloquei a imagem pois detalha melhor o erro.

Comment: Eu restaurei a imagem, mesmo que não o melhor seja o texto, os dois juntos pode ser melhor ainda ;)

Comment: Deu certo a resposta, poderia dar um feedback?

Answer (score 1):

Ao que me parece você esta tentando instalar o IDE:

- https://dl.google.com/dl/android/studio/ide-zips/1.5.1.0/android-studio-ide-141.2456560-linux.zip

Mas ainda não instalou o SDK, pra isto primeiro faça o download de:

- http://dl.google.com/android/android-sdk_r24.4.1-linux.tgz

E instale ele, depois você instala o IDE.

Fonte: http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/sdk/index.html#Other

Comment: Eu já havia feito isso, instalando manualmente o sdk sem ser baixado na hora da instalação do Android Studio, mas não tinha funfado ainda, depois de muita briga a forma como resolvi foi instalar manualmente o componente que estava faltando, que por algum motivo que não sei qual, não estava sendo instalado. Utilizo o Android Studio a um bom tempo, e nunca tinha acontecido isso. Mas enfim, ha sempre uma primeira vez. Obrigado pela ajuda, sua resposta me direcionou para a resolução.